# Button spacing when DropDownButton in bootstrap is used

Tags: reactjs, bootstrapping, react-bootstrap

I am using the `DropdownButton` component from react-bootstrap button. I have created three buttons using the `DropdownButton` component, but now I am having two issues:

1. The size of the `button` is changing based on the title of the `button`. I want all the three buttons to be of the same size.
2. All the three buttons and places vertically and there is no spacing between the buttons. I tried using 'ButtonToolBar' component and it still doesn't work.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {DropdownButton, ButtonToolbar} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {MenuItem} from 'react-bootstrap'

export default class extends Component {
    render() {

      return (
        <div className='panel panel-default panel-borderless'>
              <div className='panel-heading'><h4>Document Types</h4></div>
              <div className='panel-body container-fluid'>
                  <div className='row'>
                      <div className='col-md-12 col-lg-6'>
                          <ButtonToolbar>
                          <DropdownButton title={'Click here'} noCaret block>
                              <MenuItem eventKey='1'>Browse one</MenuItem>
                              <MenuItem eventKey='2'>Browse two</MenuItem>
                          </DropdownButton>
                          </ButtonToolbar>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className='row'>
                      <div className='col-md-12 col-lg-6'>
                          <ButtonToolbar>
                          <DropdownButton title={'Click here'} noCaret block>
                              <MenuItem eventKey='1'>Browse one</MenuItem>
                              <MenuItem eventKey='2'>Browse two</MenuItem>
                          </DropdownButton>
                          </ButtonToolbar>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className='row'>
                      <div className='col-md-12 col-lg-6'>
                          <DropdownButton title={'Click here'} noCaret block>
                              <MenuItem eventKey='1'>Browse one</MenuItem>
                              <MenuItem eventKey='2'>Browse two</MenuItem>
                          </DropdownButton>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```